# В чем может быть ошибка?

Tags: c++

Не хочет компилироваться, не принимает строчку `char[int]`, хотя это обычная инициализация массива. В чём ошибка?

```
const int N = 5;
char Mas[N];
int beg = 0;
int koli4 = N;

void push(char i)
{
    if (beg == koli4) {
        printf(":-P net mesta");
        return;
    }
    Mas[beg] = i;
    beg++;
}

char pop(char Mas)
{
    if (beg == 0) {
        printf("massiv pust");
        return 0;
    }
    beg--;
    return Mas[beg];
}

main()
{
    push('A');
    push('B');
    push('C');
    printf("%s", pop(Mas));
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Приведите точный текст ошибки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы в качестве пишете `char pop(char Mas)`. То есть внутри функции `Mas` имеет тип не char*, а char. Правильно: `char pop(char* Mas)` (проверено=)
Вторая ошибка -- функция main имеет тип возвращаемого значения int. Вернее, должна иметь.

Answer (score 2):

Первое, у вас глобальная переменная Mas - массив элементов, от сюда ошибка, первое:

```
    char pop(char Mas)
    {
    if (beg == 0) {
        printf("massiv pust");
        return 0;
        }
    beg--;
    return Mas[beg];
    }
    ...
    printf("%s", pop(Mas));
```

pop() - принимает char, а вы пытаетесь передать массив. Второе: у Вас стоит формат вывода строки, а функция возвращает char - по видимому компилятор, сам не может предугадаит Ваших действий, а значит Вам самим, нужно согласовать типы, легче всего поставить формат "%c", если я правильно понял, что вы хотите сделать.

UPD: Ошибка о которой Вы написали, поверхностная, локальная переменная в pop() Mas - не имеет оператора индексного доступа, так как это просто char, а не char[], как Вы наверное хотели ;)